# CodeIgniter can't post data

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I try to make a simply User Login in Codeigniter, but I cant get the Form Data via Post.

Look at the Simple code
Controller

```
class User extends CI_Controller{

function login(){


    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<em>','</em>');

    if($this->input->post('weiter')){

        if($this->form_validation->run()){
            echo "okay";

        }
    }else{
        $this->load->view("templates/header");  
        $this->load->view("user/login");
        $this->load->view("templates/footer");
    }





}
```

}

Routing Config

```
 $route['user/login'] = 'user/login';
```

the form:

```
<?php echo form_open("user/login");?>
<table>

    <tr>
        <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="password">Passwort</label></td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="weiter"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I look with a Developer tool from Chrome I see, it do the Post but the Return Status is 404, just why, can me help someone?

Comment: The is irrelevant ( you can remove it from you project ). If the url of this page is http://example.com/user/login you can put <?php echo form_open(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

The problem I can see is your form_open("user/login"); is not returning proper url, just remove it and test, use the following code for view

```
<form method="post">
<table>

    <tr>
        <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="password">Passwort</label></td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="weiter"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

you can optionally remove your routing rule `$route['user/login'] = 'user/login';` as you don't need it if you are not changing controller name or method name as value.

Comment: hm no it not the problem, the problem i detect is, the default controller can get the post data, but all other controller not, the result code is even by all 404 just by the default_controller not ... i dont understand that :D

Comment: at a time you can only get values in one controller, I curious how are trying to access values in other controllers

Comment: I make it how i write it on the top, I see that all controllers are display on the browser, just they have a 404 error code, that confused. I event don't need to add the Controller to the route just when I want wo override them with s spezific path, it that normally ? :D

Comment: Its not normal, just use one controller at a time. if you are using more that one controller you are putting yourself in trouble, create multiple functions as you needed, and codeigniter has very nice routing functionality you don't need to use multiple controllers

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Problem are solved, not fine but it works.
I have set in the config.php the property index_page to '' for a 
clear URL, But when the are set 'index.php' all work fine ...

Don't know if this normaly or not

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using base_url() ? maybe you have a problem in your .htaccess. try to use the code below.

```
  <?php 
    echo form_open(base_url('user/login'));
   ?>
   <table>

<tr>
    <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="password">Passwort</label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="weiter"></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
     <?php echo form_close(); 
       ?>
```